# How do I disable graphical password prompt from SSH?

Tags: ssh, x11, gui

Sometimes SSH pops up a GUI password (or host authentity) input window, which interacts poorly with Awesome window manager, prevents copy&paste of the password and is generally unnecessary for me.

How do I disable it? Trivial attempt fails:

```
$ DISPLAY= ssh root@v3eur
Error: Can't open display: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Comment: The stock OpenSSH `ssh` client can only use a GUI program for ssh passphrases. If you're getting popup dialogs for passwords or to accept host keys, that may be something added by your distro.

Comment: I’ve just seen this happening with Fedora (FC22) and KDE. A prompt appears that hijacks all input so it’s impossible to even make screenshot of it. Unfortunately my attempts at reproducing the issue failed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find which "key agent" is activated and to disable it. As you did not mentioned which Linux distribution flavour (Ubuntu?) nor which desktop (Gnome?) you are using, this is difficult to provide a clear answer.

If you are using Gnome/Unity for desktop, then you should deactivate Gnome Keyring SSh support. This can be done by prompting the `Startup Applications` application which allows you to configure applications run upon login. It should have an entry like "SSH Key Agent", just unckech it, logout and login again.

Similar technic applies to different distro and/or desktop.

Note: on some previous version of Ubuntu, this entry could be hidden, see [this post to unhide it](http://dtek.net/blog/how-stop-gnome-keyring-clobbering-opensshs-ssh-agent-ubuntu-1204).

Comment: `ssh-agent` is in use, but typically don't cause problems, it just saves the passphrase for `id_dsa`.

Comment: Yes I know. So I don't understand your question. The GUI prompt you see is probably triggered by Gnome Keyring (or equivalent depending on your installation). I'm only giving you advice how to disable it. Now if it is something different you are asking, please clarify.

Comment: I feel like this doesnt work. In XFCE (includes gnome keyring), there is a `SSH Key Agent (GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent)` entry in "Autostart" and it is disabled. Also ran `xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /startup/ssh-agent/enabled -n -t bool -s false` as described [here](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/advanced#ssh_and_gpg_agents). Still, even after relogging, the GUI prompt at ssh is still there. Removing gnome-keyring altogether works, but that would seldom be desirable...

Comment: Okay, so my abofe comment this seems to be a XFCE-side bug. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412793) are possible solutions for xfce.

Answer (score 1):

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ssh-askpass ssh-askpass-gnome
```

Fedora/CentOS/RHEL:

```
sudo yum remove openssh-askpass
```

openSUSE:

```
sudo zypper -n remove openssh-askpass-gnome
```